# Woocommerce custom content-product.php show atributtes at main page

Tags: php, woocommerce

Hello This is the basic code for the template content-product.php

>

">

```
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
?>


<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
?>
```

I want to show specific attributes title and atributes term under the attribute title.

here is the link of the design: https://ibb.co/5GG2xwt